# porque los campos que vienen de otro formulario no se actualizan? xamarin form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

tengo un formulario "Consulta" donde despliega una lista de clientes y cuando lo selecciono el nombre me lo guarda en una clase que uso para compartir informacion entre formularios

```
   Detalle det = new Detalle();
    private void LvElementos_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var element = e.SelectedItem as ElementosLista_clientes;
            lvElementos.SelectedItem = null;
            ElementosLista_clientes.Nombre_buscado = element.Nombre; 
            Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
            det.nom();            

        }
    }
```

El det.nom() viene de la clase detalle donde despliego la informacion de la consulta pero el problema es que se ejecuta el metodo pero los datos que requiero visualizar no se actualizan

```
 public void nom()
    {
        entBuscar.Text = "";
        lblCliente.Text = ElementosLista_clientes.Nombre_buscado;

    }
```

Comment: ¿Tu clase ElementosLista_clientes implementa la interface INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Hola y como estas pasando el dato al otro formulario? Pero puedes pasar por constructor, por una variable Global en la clase App.cs, puedes suscribirte al MessageCenter<T>.  Saludos